# Having different ibdata file for multiple databases

Tags: mysql

I have my MySQL server running with 4 databases and innodb_data_file_path set to the default configuration[ibdata1]. I see the size of this file on disk growing as big as 1GB. This file will only grow as the application that runs this server is collecting the monitoring data.

Just not sure how this will have performance issue with such a large file size.

Is there a way to split this file per database? so that each database can have its own ibdata file. I know InnoDB has an option where this data file can be split per table (still maintaining a shared tablespace), but could not find any option to split this file per database.

Can someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this option to my.cnf : *innodb_file_per_table*

Reference :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html

Comment: Well, per database is not exactly same as per table.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a separate tablespace file per database already. You should see an ibdata file in each subdirectory for the different databases in the mysql data directory.